# How to tell faces apart in MATLAB pde toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I created a 3d geometry for my pde model, but it is not so clear what the faces are referring to. Is there any way to clearly distinguish them?

```
a=25/3; %semi major axis

%generate alphashape
[az,el,r] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi-0.01,60),linspace(-pi,0,60),[0.99,1]);
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(az,el,r);
x=x*a;
y=y*a;
z=z+1;
shp = alphaShape(x(:),y(:),z(:),0.25);
% plot(shp);

%applying the geometry to the model
[elements,nodes] = boundaryFacets(shp);
nodes = nodes';
elements = elements';
model = createpde();
geometryFromMesh(model,nodes,elements);
pdegplot(model,'FaceLabels','on','FaceAlpha',0.5);
```

**Edit:**
Is it safe to say that `F1` is the bottom face, `F2` is the top one and `F3` is the circumference? because I get strange results for my model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a 3D geometry you have 3D elements, and each of them is defined by 2D faces. Each face is each plane that defines the geometry.

In the MATLAB example

[image]

The faces are each of those grey patches. The elements however are 3D regions. Generally when plotting it is easier to plot the faces, and not show all the inside structure.

Comment: thank you for you answer, i understand the meaning of faces, but in my figure it is not so clear. i have uploaded an image.

Comment: @yonatan I dont understand. Are you asking if you understand your picture correctly? I assume so